# Firefox add-on bug 04-May-2019 - cannot enable "studies"

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

So Firefox has disabled the half a dozen plugins I'm using, essentially [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1432789/all-of-my-firefox-add-ons-been-disabled-suddenly-how-can-i-re-enable-them). Instead of blindly trusting, using the `xpinstall.signatures.required = false`, hack, I would like to have FF update itself using the "studies" thing [described here](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2019/05/04/update-regarding-add-ons-in-firefox/).

Only... I cannot activate that preferences, the options are grayed out:

[image]

Firefox is 60.6.1esr (64-bit) on Debian stable (Stretch). Could be because

```
firefox toolkit.telemetry.enabled status=locked
```

?

Comment: Great, so they can remotely break the browser, and I can't fix it?

Comment: [This answer, an `about:config` tweak, should solve your problem on Debian.](https://superuser.com/a/1432804/541767)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All of my Firefox add-ons been disabled suddenly, how can I re-enable them?](https://superuser.com/questions/1432789/all-of-my-firefox-add-ons-been-disabled-suddenly-how-can-i-re-enable-them)